# Watchguard box VPN Access X700

Tags: vpn, watchguard

We have a watchguard X700 box that we are trying to get VPN access through. We have had a play with the ports and tried to open the VPN access but still have no joy.

Do we need to purchase a special licence to get VPN open on this box?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need anything additional for an ipsec or pptp VPN.  What problems are you actually seeing in the logs, other than "no joy"?